# Seeking clarification about mysql 5.6 memcache integration

Tags: mysql, nosql, memcached

I'm having trouble getting a clear understanding of what MySQL 5.6 is introducing w/r/t memcache.

As I understand it, memcache by itself is essentially a huge, shared, memory-resident hash table that is managed by a server, **memcached**.  In particular, it knows nothing about a persistent data store, and offers no services in that regard.  It simply knows about **keys** and **values** (like a Perl hash).

What I *think* mySQL 5.6 introduces is a **NoSQL API**, whereby mySQL clients can request data *from the mySQL server* by key, rather than by a SELECT statement.  (And similarly, they can perform updates with key=value pairs).  MySQL uses **memcached** to cache these in memory as a performance boost, but also takes care of things like writing updates back to the database before they age out of the cache, etc.

In other words, the use of **memcached** is an implementation detail of the mySQL 5.6 NoSQL feature, and is not something the application programmer needs to be aware of.

I'd welcome any corrections or amplification to my understanding.

Thanks,
Chap

Answer (score 2):

I think it's quite simple (from the official documentation):

I disagree with your last sentence, the application programmer has to be really aware of the memcache plugin because having it onboard of the MySQL server means that he can decide (maybe he will be forced to) access data through a memcached language interface or via the SQL interface

To better understand the impact of this plugin onto an app design you should know that there are 3 configuration tables used by MySQL for a proper memcached management; understanding how the "cache_policies" works will shade some light to some of your doubts:

> Table cache_policies specifies whether to use InnoDB as the data store of memcached (innodb_only), or to use the traditional memcached engine as the backstore (cache-only), or both (caching). In the last case, if memcached cannot find a key in memory, it searches for the value in an InnoDB table.

here is the link: [innodb-memcached-internals](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/innodb-memcached-internals.html)

This quote above means that, depending on what you decided for a specific key-value, you will have different application scenarios :

1. innodb_only -> means that you can query the data via a sql interface or via a memcached interface, here is a link to some memcached language interface examples [memcached-interfaces](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/ha-memcached-interfaces.html)

   1. cache-only -> means that you should query the data via the memchached interface only
   2. caching -> means that you can use both the interfaces (note that the storage mechanism slightly changes)

Of course this latter configuration decision is strictly related to your specific needs

Answer (score 1):

I don't really have a complete answer for you I'm afraid, as I too am struggling to find the detail I require before toying around with it.

That said however there is one important point which I have managed to uncover that you seem to have missed, namely that by accessing the InnoDB storage engine via the new plugin you are actually completely bypassing SQL and avoiding all the overhead that comes with it.

This of course makes it essentially a key/value store more akin to most NoSQL databases complete with all the drawbacks associated with them. i.e. no joins etc...

However on the flip side for many applications these days, this is exactly what we want.  There has been only a handful of real world performance mentions that I have come across but all seem to point to this implementation significantly outperforming MongoDB and other similar NoSQL solutions (how much truth is in it I do not know) with even one (relatively in depth) comparison claiming as high as 700k qps on a commodity server (compared with around 100k on a well tuned MySQL setup), which is incredible if true.

Resource here:

http://yoshinorimatsunobu.blogspot.co.uk/search/label/handlersocket

Anyway, sorry I can't be any more help but its food for thought at least!

Comment: Pretty amazing numbers from that blog.  So what I still don't seem to be able to find is a specification of MySQL's "NoSQL" API.  I gather that it maps closely with memcached's API, but I'm having a hard time finding the spec.